# How to disable full keyboard keys using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, keyboard

I want to disable full key boards keys using Javascript or jQuery.

And also, is it possible to disable to keyboard using PHP script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Can you clarify, with examples?

Comment: hi Michael , means i am creating user login form in that case user  can not use keyboard all key board not working on this page

Comment: no  for web on browser

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return false;
}
```

for specific area try this

```
$(".class").keydown(function(event) { 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Harish Singh and Mohit Gupta  Are you sure this will work for all keyboard keys?. Including Alt+f4, Alt+tab,Escape(when window full screen mode activate), and Print Screen button. Please Reply me..

Answer (score 1):

While cancelling the `keydown` effect works for *most* keys out-of-the-box, some special combos (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for reload, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for new tab, etc) can't be blocked in this way and are always sent to the browser instead.

The new (and, at the time of writing, experimental) [Keyboard Lock API](https://web.dev/keyboard-lock/) allows you to capture these kinds of key presses. You can use it like so, or you can also pass in an array of key codes if you only want to lock some of them.

```
navigator.keyboard.lock();
```

When you're done, you can call

```
navigator.keyboard.unlock();
```

to stop capturing these key codes.

Note that you'll still need to listen for and respond to the `keydown` event - the new API allows you to capture these lower-level key presses, but you still need to define what will happen when they're pressed.

In your case this would just be cancelling the event (in the style of [@Harish Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19628112)), but other use cases would involve performing other actions when certain sets of keys are pressed, prehaps closing the document open in your web app with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> rather than the tab, or opening a pause menu when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed in a full-screen game, rather than exiting fullscreen.

---

You can [try the Keyboard Lock API](https://keyboard-lock.glitch.me/) today, but [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_keyboard_lock) is currently limited to Chrome and other Chromium browsers (Edge and Opera) on desktop.

---

One last note is that for security reasons, the user can always exit the keyboard lock via a browser gesture, to prevent them from getting trapped (which could happen if you used this in conjunction with the [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API)). In Chrome, this exit gesture is to **hold** the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key for 2 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Try this .

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: false for windows key