# Auto load full screen mode

Tags: javascript, html

How to open a web page using auto full screen mode?

I am looking for a solution to open an web page automatically in full screen mode, when page is loaded.
At this moment I can do it when I clicked a button.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1>Screen Orientation Lock Demo</h1>
<button class="lock">Lock</button>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>


var fullscreen = {
  request: function(elem){
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
  },
};


$('.lock').on('click', function() {
  fullscreen.request(this.parentNode);
});

function myFunction() {
    fullscreen.request(this.parentNode);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable full keyboard keys using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628081/how-to-disable-full-keyboard-keys-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: you need user input to go fullscreen, you can't do it automatically

Comment: then how if i give this "document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();" on my function? @kkarakk

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen):

> This method must be called while responding to a user interaction or a device orientation change; otherwise it will fail.

So, the *requestFullScreen* method should be called after a user interaction with the page or on orientation change.