# Disable keyboard when using fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html

I'm following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628081/how-to-disable-full-keyboard-keys-using-javascript-or-jquery) for disable keyboard events. But this only works for inputs form.
I just want when fullscreen mode is actived user cannot use keyboard.
this is my snipet codepen.io/adityadees/pen/Jzqmpy

```js
  document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return false;
}
```

```html
<body onload="document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();">
  <h1>Lock</h1> 
  
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: There is no way to completely disable the keyboard with JS. All browser and OS level shortcuts will be available anyway

Comment: Just listen to `onresize` event and see if `window.innerHeight === screen.height`

Comment: @samb102 How is that related with disabling keyboard?

Comment: As @EriksKlotins already mentioned there is no way to fully disable the keyboard through JS. The best you can do is ignore interactions with your application that come from the keyboard. Consider the security implications if a total lockdown was allowed by the operating system.

Comment: so no way for make user stay at fullscreen mode? I just want to make my browser stay at fullscreen mode  @EriksKlotins

Comment: @AdityaDS, no you cannot enforce that with web tools. Perhaps, look at kiosk mode to limit what users can do with the computer.

Answer (score 0):

**F11 and ESC will work**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
     $(document).keydown(function (event) {
            return false;
        });
    });
    document.oncontextmenu = function (e)        //check for the right click
    {
        return false;
    }
    document.ondragstart = function (e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    function toggleFullScreen() {

                                        var docElm = document.documentElement;
                                        if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
                                            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                                                docElm.requestFullscreen();
                                            }
                                            else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                                                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
                                            }
                                            else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                                                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {


                                            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                                                document.exitFullscreen();
                                            }
                                            else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                                                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                                            }
                                            else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                                                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                                            }



                                        }
                                    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <input type=text id="text"/>
    <button onclick="toggleFullScreen()" value="toggleFullScreen" name="toggleFullScreen">toggleFullScreen</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I can still using Esc or F11 to out from fullscreen. i want to disable so user will stay at fullscreen mode

Comment: There is no way to disable all key from browser level

Comment: even for avoid exit from fullscreen mode?